# How to get a script to work on all desired sheets at once

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a script I am using that works on a single tab/sheet but I would like the same process & script to work on 4 tabs. Should be easy enough?

Each tab is an employee name, and when the clicking a checkbox "sold" it moves the entire row to the "sold" tab. But again, it only works on one and I need it to work on four.

Additionally, once I get this squared away I would like to do the same but when checking "lost" it goes to the "lost" tab.  I have a screenshot to show what I mean, and also the script I am using below. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tcC4.jpg)

```
1 function onEdit(e) {
2  const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
3 const r = e.range;
4  if (src.getName() != "Cynthia" || r.columnStart != 9 || r.rowStart == 2) return;
5 const dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sold");
6  src.getRange(r.rowStart,1,1,8).moveTo(dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,1,8));
7  src.deleteRow(r.rowStart);
8 }
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Sheet.getName()` and `String.match()` with a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html), like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  let sheet;
  if (e.range.columnStart !== 9
    || e.range.rowStart === 2
    || !(sheet = e.range.getSheet()).getName().match(/^(Cynthia|Dweezil|Moon Unit|Ringo)$/i)) {
    return;
  };
  const targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sold');
  const targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
  sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, 8).moveTo(targetRange);
  sheet.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
}
```

Comment: Okay- I have tried time and time again to utilize this same script & formatting to try to also get the "lost" checkbox to move to the "lost" tab (on the same script) and I've been at a loss. Any help on how to get two identical actions/scripts to work simultaneously?

Comment: Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741). Post a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).